# Ubuntu 20.04 is only recognizing 64Gb of 128Gb installed RAM

Tags: 20.04, ram

How can I get it to recognize my full memory block?  My bios is correctly reporting that the 128Gb is installed, and my Windows dual-boot is working likewise [update: Windows is actually reporting 64Gb as "hardware reserved"].

Edit:  Here is the readout.  I am suspecting this is a bios issue (Dell R9: H370 chipset which is not enabled beyond 64Gb despite the capability existing within the chipset).

```
*-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Alienware
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0.9
       date: 06/03/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 27
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 128GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/32GX
          vendor: AMD
          physical id: 0
          serial: 8C92E328
          slot: XMM3
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/32GX
          vendor: AMD
          physical id: 1
          serial: B4930101
          slot: XMM1
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/32GX
          vendor: AMD
          physical id: 2
          serial: D992E6C2
          slot: XMM4
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 3200 MHz (0.3 ns)
          product: KHX3200C16D4/32GX
          vendor: AMD
          physical id: 3
          serial: B49301B1
          slot: XMM2
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 3200MHz (0.3ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 2e
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 512KiB
       capacity: 512KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 2f
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 30
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 16MiB
       capacity: 16MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: Memory controller
       product: 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ea100000-ea103fff
```

Output from free command:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       65687828    20543396    39242456      654344     5901976    43761244
Swap:      16777212           0    16777212
```

Comment: In a terminal, `sudo lshw -C memory`, and see the boot-time recognition of memory `sudo journalctl  -b 0`.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have pasted the results of the first above.  The second provides an extensive readout.  I have omitted pasting realizing that this is likely a bios issue.  I was incorrect about Windows.  It does recognize the ram, but denotes 64Gb as "hardware reserved".  I understand there may be bios edits I can make to permit usage.  I will be looking at that next.  Thank you!

Comment: What does `free` command output? Ubuntu doesn't "recognize" other amount of RAM as is installed. I see 128 installed.

Comment: Added above.  thank you.

Comment: `cat /proc/cmdline` please and also check the BIOS for any possible limitation. Sometimes those limitations get lifted over time, btw. Your mentioning of Windows and it only seeing 64 GB as well (plus 64 GB reserved) strongly suggests that the BIOS has a hand in this. Have you tried `fwupdmgr update` as `root` from your Ubuntu to see if there are BIOS updates available?

Comment: Output below.  I suspect bios at this point as well.  I have found a site with bios edit instructions which I will pursue next:             BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-59-generic root=UUID=c819491e-949d-432e-ba23-59db21aab8f4 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7

Comment: I should add...no bios updates available that address this issue as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this was a bios limitation.  While the chipset was capable of recognizing the full memory available, the manufacturer (Dell Aurora R9) did not enable the capability.  Frustrating, but that's the outcome.

Comment: Is there any way this can be altered ? Bios update etc. ?
I have Aurora R10 and with Ubuntu I can't increase RAM beyond 64 GB.

Comment: Ultimately i ended up replacing the Dell motherboard and reusing the components.